# Raspberry PI real-time video streaming with overlay

Tags: video, streaming, overlay, raspberry-pi

I'm playing with various video streaming options for raspberry camera. Currently the best solution that has the lowest delay is to pipe data from `raspivid` to `nc` and then to `mplayer`

On raspberry:

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -t 0 -hf -vf -w 640 -h 480 --nopreview -o - | nc -l 5000
```

On client machine (`-fps 60` trick to skip buffering)

```
nc $RASP_IP 5000 | mplayer -nosound -framedrop -x 640 -y 480 -fps 60 -demuxer +h264es -cache 1024 -
```

This work really nice with almost zero delay.

Now I would like to overlay some dynamic data onto the video. What would be the best way to achieve that?

I've seen solutions like editing `raspivid` and adding opencv directly but this won't work in my case since the display must be on different machine than the one connected to camera.

The technology (language/library) doesn't matter that much unless it can run on *nix (.NET is not an option)

Comment: Here's an example of doing this using pygame to display the video and provide the overlay. https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-wifi-raspberry-pi-touch-cam/overview

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of commands I use to stream the Pi camera over a network using multicast, and writing the time and camera name on the bottom of the image.  I have put comments in between each line to explain what it does, but the commands themselves must be all on the same line without any comments to actually work (one line starting with `v4l2-ctl`, another line starting with `ffmpeg`).

```
# Set up the camera device for dynamic framerate (to get better images in
# low light) and for uncompressed video output.
v4l2-ctl
  -d /dev/video0
  --set-ctrl=exposure_dynamic_framerate=1
  --set-ctrl=scene_mode=8
  -v width=1296,height=960,pixelformat=YU12

# Run ffmpeg.
ffmpeg

  # Select the frame size.  This is for the Pi camera v1 and must match the
  # size set above in v4l2-ctl.
  -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1296x960

  # Use the system clock because the camera stream doesn't have timestamps.
  -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1

  # Select the first camera.  This could change if you have multiple
  # cameras connected (e.g. via USB)
  -i /dev/video0

  # Set the framerate in the output H264 stream.  This value is double
  # the actual framerate, so 30 means 15 fps.
  -bsf h264_metadata=tick_rate=30

  # Use a video filter
  -vf '

    # Make the video higher by 37 pixels (32 for the words and 5 for padding)
    pad=h=(in_h+5+32),

    # Write the time at the bottom right.
    drawtext=x=(w-tw-8):y=(h-28):fontcolor=white:fontsize=28:text=%{localtime},

    # Write the hostname on the bottom left, which we put in the file
    # /tmp/cam_hostname before running this command.
    drawtext=x=8:y=(h-28):fontcolor=white:fontsize=28:textfile=/tmp/cam_hostname,

    # Write another message from /tmp/cam_msg after the hostname.  This
    # file is read each frame, so it can contain live data such as the
    # temperature or motion sensor status.  The file contents must be
    # written by another program.
    drawtext=x=32:y=(h-28):fontcolor=white:fontsize=28:textfile=/tmp/cam_msg:reload=1

  # End of -vf parameter
  '

  # Duplicate or drop frames as needed to ensure a constant output framerate.
  # This is because the Pi camera is set to a dynamic framerate, so at night
  # the framerate will drop to give a brighter image.  This option ensures
  # that whatever the camera framerate, the output H264 framerate will be
  # constant.
  -vsync 1

  # Specify the output framerate.  We use 15 fps because that's the camera's
  # maximum in high resolution mode.
  -r 15

  # Use the hardware H264 encoder via the V4L2 M2M interface.
  -c:v h264_v4l2m2m

  # Set the bitrate of the output video.
  -b:v 5M

  # No audio.
  -an

  # Adjust the output H264 bitstream so the timestamps run at the correct
  # rate.  This is required so if the stream is recorded, media players will
  # seek accurately (e.g. seeking 10 seconds forward will go forward 10
  # seconds).  Without this, seeking forward by 10 seconds could jump forward
  # by a minute or more, making it difficult to seek around in the
  # recorded footage.
  -bsf 'setts=ts=N*(1/15)*100000,h264_metadata=tick_rate=30'

  # Output the final stream via RTP to a multicast IP address.
  -f rtp_mpegts udp://239.0.0.3:5004
```